# Set form body data on-the-fly after "Submit" click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, playframework-2.0

This does not work, and I don't understand why...

`upload.html`

```
@form(action = routes.MainController.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

    <label for="some_value">Some Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="something"><br/>

    <label for="some_other_value">Some Other Label</label>
    <input type="text" name="something_else"><br/>

    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>
}

<span/>
<script>
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if (dataReady()) {
        $( "span" ).text( "Good to go..." ).show();
        var formData = $(this);
        var bodyData = getClientGeneratedBlob();
        formData.append("blob", bodyData);
    } else {
        $( "span" ).text( "Not ready!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>
```

Why isn't the data being received in the request?  How do I properly append the blob to this form?

Comment: do you use any framework for this?

Comment: @Ryan Does not appear where variable `blob` is defined? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @guest271314 Didn't think it would matter. I get it through quite of bit of other code... I have stepped through the code with Developer Tools and see that it is a non-null "Blob" object.

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake Just [Play](http://www.playframework.com/) (`@form` from [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms))

Comment: @Ryan Interesting. Is it possible to create a `URL` object and view the `Blob` in a separate `tab` or `window` ? No need for `new Blob(["blob"], {"type" : "text/html"})` ? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it is. I got this working by making the request manually (I'll copy/paste as an answer below.) Not what I consider an acceptable solution though; I'd like to know why the above didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, but I am not going to mark it as a solution considering I prefer fixing the above code in the question.  This is more of a hack...

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if (dataReady()) {
    $( "span" ).text( "Good to go..." ).show();
    var dataArray = $(this).serializeArray(), len = dataArray.length, dataObj = {};
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      dataObj[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
    }
    sendFormToServer( dataObj["something"], dataObj["something_else"] );
    $( "span" ).text( "Successfully saved your awesome blob" ).show();
  } else {
    $( "span" ).text( "You must create something first!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
  }
});
```

Where...

```
function sendFormToServer( some_name, some_other_name ) {
  if (!currentBlob) {
    alert("Cannot send an empty blob!");
  }
  var url = "/some_path";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();      
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fd = new FormData();

  fd.append('blah', currentBlob, 'blah');
  fd.append('something', some_name);
  fd.append('something_else', some_other_name);

  request.open("POST", url, true);
  request.send( fd );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't work because you are manipulating the DOM, not a `FormData` object as in the code from your answer.

```
var formData = $(this);
...
formData.append("blob", bodyData);
```

In the first line you are getting a reference to your `<form>` tag. You are then calling `append()` on that HTML tag. This is normally used to add new HTML elements to your page. In your case, `"blob"` is probably seen as just a text node and `bodyData` is probably just ignored. You don't see it because your form is submitting, but if you called `event.preventDefault()` you would see that the text, "blob", has appeared somewhere on your page at the end of your form.

What you're doing would work if you were, for example, adding a new `<input>` element with some data to the form right before it submits. I don't think that will work in this case though. Since you are already using it you might want to explore jQuery's `.ajax` method. It'll be pretty similar to what you have on your answer but probably more cross-browser friendly.